# How to do division using Beaver Multiplication Triples

Tags: multiparty-computation

It is very straight-forward and intuitively to achieve addition, subtraction and even generalized polynomial using Beaver's Multiplication Triples. However division seems difficult to achieve on two secret-shared values (each with precision $f$).

Assuming the case of *secure two-party computation*, there are two secret values

$$[a]\leftarrow\{0,1\}^n, [b]\leftarrow\{0,1\}^n$$

And we want to securely compute

$$c= \Bigl\lfloor\dfrac{a}{b}\Bigr\rfloor$$

where $c$ is an integer.

So my question is : How to design a such division protocol, or is there any papers? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There exists a number of *general* multiparty protocols that can securely compute any function. Some of these, for instance [SPDZ](https://eprint.iacr.org/2011/535) and [this one](https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/816), use Beaver triples. These protocols can compute integer division, since integer division is a function.

However, using general multiparty protocols may not be the most practical or efficient. So there has also been some research in *specialized* protocols for integer division. There is e.g. a paper describing a secure two-party protocol for integer division [here](https://eprint.iacr.org/2012/164). The "related work" section in that paper contains references to other integer division protocols for more than two parties. I'm not sure any of these protocols use Beaver triples, though.